# query not firing on ios, not responsive in chrome mobile, but good in pc

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

here is my js file, which i put in my assets/js folder

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Internet").hide();
    $(".Game").hide();
    $(".Emoney").hide();
    $(".Telpon").hide();
    $(".OjekOnline").hide();
    $(".Tcash").hide();
    $(".Pulsa").hide();
  });

  function cek(value){
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Internet").hide();
    $(".Game").hide();
    $(".Emoney").hide();
    $(".Telpon").hide();
    $(".OjekOnline").hide();
    $(".Tcash").hide();
    $(".Pulsa").hide();
  });
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("."+value).show();
  });
  }
```

and this is my view, and i've link my js file

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url().'assets/cssfile/mycss.css'?>">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/myjs.js'?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js'?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var base_url = "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/package/daftarpaket/'?>";
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="w3-content" style="max-width:400px" id="beli" >
    <h5 class="w3-container w3-center w3-padding-64"><span class="w3-tag w3-wide">Solusi mager-Mu</span></h5>
    <div id="tableContainer-1">
    <div id="tableContainer-2">
        <form id="myForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/package/insert'?>">
            <table id="myTable">
                <tr>
                <td>Jenis Produk</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="jenisProduk" id="JP" onclick="cek(this.value)">
                          <option value=''></option>"
                          <option value='Internet'>Internet</option>"
                          <option value='Game'>Game</option>"
                          <option value='Emoney'>Emoney</option>"
                          <option value='Telpon'>Telpon</option>"
                          <option value='OjekOnline'>OjekOnline</option>"
                          <option value='Tcash'>Tcash</option>"
                          <option value='Pulsa'>Pulsa</option>"
</select>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Provider</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><select id="prov" onchange="cekInput()">
                      <option></option>
                      <option value="Telkomsel" class="Internet">Telkomsel</option>
                      <option value="XL" class="Internet">Xl</option>
                      <option value="Indosat" class="Internet">Indosat</option>
                      <option value="Axis" class="Internet">Axis</option>
                      <option value="Three" class="Internet">Three</option>
                      <option value="Bolt" class="Internet">Bolt</option>
                      <option value="BNI" class="Emoney">BNI</option>
                      <option value="Mandiri" class="Emoney">Mandiri</option>
                      <option value="MoBa" class="Game">MoBa</option>
                      <option value="PUBG" class="Game">PUBG</option>
                      <option value="SteamWallet" class="Game">SteamWallet</option>
                      <option value="Telkomsel" class="Telpon">Telkomsel</option>
                      <option value="XL" class="Telpon">Xl</option>
                      <option value="Three" class="Telpon">Three</option>
                      <option value="GoPay" class="OjekOnline">GoPay</option>
                      <option value="GRAB" class="OjekOnline">GRAB</option>
                      <option value="Telkomsel" class="Tcash">Telkomsel</option>
                      <option value="Telkomsel" class="Pulsa">Telkomsel</option>
                      <option value="XL" class="Pulsa">Xl</option>
                      <option value="Indosat" class="Pulsa">Indosat</option>
                      <option value="Axis" class="Pulsa">Axis</option>
                      <option value="Three" class="Pulsa">Three</option>
                      <option value="Bolt" class="Pulsa">Bolt</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                </tr>
</table>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

first, i want to hide the option of this

```
<select id="prov" onchange="cekInput()">
```

but it wont hide and keep on showing if im using ios,
and if im using chrome for mobile, it not resposive, i need to click

```
<select name="jenisProduk" id="JP" onclick="cek(this.value)">
```

for twice to show the hiding item.
but work fine in pc and desktop.

Comment: is the problem about your design?

Comment: yes, hide and showing option after choosing another option

Comment: do you use bootstrap?

Comment: no i dont, because i dont know how to use it, any suggestion for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the bootstrap.

Step 1: [Click here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) to and read how to import bootstrap.

Step 2: You can use `<div class="form-group">` to build your responsive form. And then you can write `class="form-control"` in your `<input>` or `<select></select>` or another forming.